# adding xml configuration on application.yml logging.config

Tags: xml, spring

I have a logback-spring.xml in my resources folder together with my application.yml

i added the code below on my application.yml

```
logging:
    config: logback-spring.xml
```

contents of logback-spring.xml was based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920025/6428837)

it does not create the log with the filename I indicated below

```
<file>/var/log/mylog.log</file>    
...   
<fileNamePattern>/var/log/mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

any idea how to get this working?

Comment: you would not need classpath prefix as long you can put them in folders such as 'resources' (maven project )

Comment: i've removed classpath prefix but still does not create the file that i needed, thanks anw

Answer (score 0):

it should be **logging.file**,

logging.file=/var/log/mylog.log

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly

Comment: i need a logging that allows a daily rollover implementation for archiving purposes that's why i needed the logback-spring.xml, **fileNamePattern** was set to `%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}` for testing purposes only