# How to change the name of the log file in Spring Boot with the help of logging properties

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot

As the Log files will rotate when they reach 10 Mb and as with console output, so old logs will be deleted or been overwritten. Can you please help me how to create the log file with named as appName_timestamp(dd-mm-yyyy)??

Comment: check the answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918323/how-to-configure-rolling-file-appender-within-spring-boots-application-yml

Comment: But its using the Logback.xml file, I want to do it with the help of logging properties only ..thanks for the reply