# spring boot logback rolling file append-er not working

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-consul

I am developing a spring boot application, where I am reading the logback configuration from a YML file which is in Consul . Following are the configuration I have used in the YML file.

```
logging:
  file: ./logs/application.log
  pattern:
    console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"
    file: "%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework.web: ERROR
    com.myapp.somepackage: DEBUG
  appenders:
    logFormat: "%d %-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n"
    currentLogFilename: ./logs/application.log
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
    archivedFileCount: 7
    timeZone: UTC
    maxFileSize: 30KB
    maxHistory: 30
```

Now the log files are generated, but the rolling appender is not working, any help on this, I am seraching for something similar like following when we perform rolling appender froma logback.xml file

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
     the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
    <fileNamePattern>./logs/myapp/application_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
    <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

The same I need to configure from a YML file

Comment: Any help on this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search what I found is, this is not yet supported in spring boot. The options are only :

```
# LOGGING
logging.config= # Location of the logging configuration file. For instance `classpath:logback.xml` for Logback
logging.exception-conversion-word=%wEx # Conversion word used when logging exceptions.
logging.file= # Log file name. For instance `myapp.log`
logging.level.*= # Log levels severity mapping. For instance `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`
logging.path= # Location of the log file. For instance `/var/log`
logging.pattern.console= # Appender pattern for output to the console. Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.pattern.file= # Appender pattern for output to the file. Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.pattern.level= # Appender pattern for log level (default %5p). Only supported with the default logback setup.
logging.register-shutdown-hook=false # Register a shutdown hook for the logging system when it is initialized.
```

So , dont waste your time on this for now. It will roll after 20MB , but the file name is like ${your_file_name}.log.1 etc. Spring should give support to give the rolling filename pattern to us. And also it is not an archived file.