# How to roll log file daily in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

I deployed a spring-boot application on CentOS 6.5.
The application is started by command 'service app start'.
Below is content of app.conf.

```
JAVA_HOME=/xxx
LOG_FOLDER=/xxx
```

I am confused that how to roll log file daily.
There is no logback.xml or any other logback configuration in application.properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place new `logback.xml` and write your appenders accordingly and place it in classpath, the `application.properties` will automatically look for it.

For more info please refer [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)
For appenders it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918323/how-to-configure-rolling-file-appender-within-spring-boots-application-yml)

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood that the log file configured in `app.conf` is the default log file of logback. Now I find out that it is output of console. I added logback-spring.xml and config with RollingFileAppender. It worked!