# Spring boot requests log

Tags: spring-boot, logging, request, embedded-jetty

I have a Spring Boot + Jetty embedded server + Apache camel.
How to log all requests to daily rolling file?
For logging exceptions I'm using log4j2.

Answer (score 1):

You can place new `logback.xml` and write your appenders accordingly and place it in classpath, the `application.properties` will automatically look for it.

For more info please refer [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)
For appenders it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918323/how-to-configure-rolling-file-appender-within-spring-boots-application-yml)