# YAML based log rolling in spring 2.6.7 not triggering

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, logback

First, I referenced [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918323/how-to-configure-rolling-file-appender-within-spring-boots-application-yml) and [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/html/features.html#features.logging), and various articles like [this one](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example), but I'm obviously missing something.

I have tried various combinations. What I currently have is

```
logging:
  level.root: trace
  file:
    name: ${PWD}/logs/spring.log
    max-size       : 1MB
    max-history    : 3
    total-size-cap : 2MB
  pattern:
    file              : "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] [%class{36}] - %msg%n"
    console           : ${logging.pattern.file}
    rolling-file-name : ${PWD}/logs/archive.%i.log
```

also tried

```
logging.logback.rollingpolicy:
    file-name-pattern : ${PWD}/logs/${spring.application.name}.%i.log
    max-file-size     : 2MB
```

With root log level set to TRACE the logs go over 2MB almost immediately.

It works fine when we use a separate XML file to configure logback, but we're trying to remove the need.

Comment: when i use rolling with YAML, *FileNamePattern* needs to contain a valid DateToken. like  followe worked.  'logging.logback.rollingpolicy.file-name-pattern: ${PWD}/logs/${spring.application.name}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'

Comment: Tried that too, though I don't see any yaml triggers for rolling by date. Didn't change anything. :(

Comment: @PaulHodges I got it working. I did something. I will update with the new answer. Give me sometime.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best yaml logback configuration that's working for me with lot of difficulties:

```
logging:
  file:
    path: /Volumes/Local Disk/logs
    name: spring.log
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
       total-size-cap: 1MB
       max-history: 3
       max-file-size: 1MB
       file-name-pattern: /Volumes/Local Disk/logs/spring.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}.%i.log.gz
  level:
     root: trace
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @PaulHodges Please accept this if this has helped you in anyway. I think this should work but the only doubt I have is about its stability via properties. Otherwise, it will work as expected.

Comment: Will check it today and confirm.

Comment: I finally got it to roll, but can't set the file name, or the size. I can tell it where to build subdirectories, but can't set the names of those either. Thanks for the help, upvoted the effort, but still nowhere close to solved. :(

Comment: @PaulHodges At least, it's rolling. :) I guess the question was about why rolling was not happening.

Comment: Not really. It's rolling as the new default behavior at 10MB. I really want to be able to control size, number, name, and location of the archives as well as the original log. What actually *triggers* the log aside from the defaults?